# Wordpress Category > Posts Orderby

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by, categories

I am trying to order the posts by title, but i just cant get it to work, I have tried to insert orderby to query_posts but I dont think i get the logic of how you write query_posts values when you can add more then one setting with &.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
$catlist = get_categories('hide_empty=0&child_of=' . $cat_id);
$cat_child = get_field('frontend_name' , 'category_'  . get_query_var('cat' ));

foreach($catlist as $categories_item) {
    echo "<ol>";
    echo '<h3><a href="' . get_category_link( $categories_item->term_id ) . '" ' . '>' . $categories_item->description .'</a> </h3> ';
    query_posts("cat=" . $categories_item->term_id . "&post_per_page=9999");

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?>
   </a></li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php echo "</ol>"; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Really thanks if you can help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that passing an associative array makes it a little easier to digest. Try this:

```
// Refactored query arguments
query_posts(array(
  'cat' => $categories_item->term_id,
  'posts_per_page' => 9999,
  'order' => 'ASC', //order ascending
  'orderby' => 'title' //order by title
));
```